# Sublime 2 Plugin: Replace Text without moving viewport

Tags: sublimetext2

I am writing a simple plugin that changes the whole content of a Sublime editor and replaces it with something else. When doing this

```
viewRegion = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())  
everything = self.view.substr(viewRegion)
self.view.replace(edit, viewRegion, everything)
```

the view scrolls to the top. How do I prevent this or restore the original viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, there isn't really a good way. You can try to get around the replace as much as possible (e.g. by using the excellent [merge_utils](https://github.com/enginespot/js-beautify-sublime/blob/master/libs/merge_utils.py)), but this will always change the position after the command is finished.

As a hack, you can save the position and restore it in a timeout like this:

```
  def format(self, edit):
    self.curpos = self.view.viewport_position()
    self.selection = self.view.sel()[0]
    viewRegion = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())  
    everything = self.view.substr(viewRegion)
    # do something useful
    self.view.replace(edit, viewRegion, everything)
    # reestablish selection
    sublime.set_timeout(self.reset_pos, 0)

  def reset_pos(self):
    self.view.sel().clear()
    self.view.sel().add(self.selection)
    self.view.set_viewport_position(self.curpos, False)
```